# $\det^{-1}(0)$ is a submanifold of $M_2(\mathbb R) \setminus \{0\}$. Is this also a submanifold of the whole space $M_2(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I want to show that the space of matrices of rank $1$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^4$.

I know the determinant function on $2\times 2$ real matrices is smooth.

I know if $f: M \to N$ is a smooth submersion, then each level set is a properly embedded submanifold of codimension $\dim(N)$.

If we consider the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices minus the zero matrix, then the level set of $\det^{-1}(0)$ is the matrices of rank $1$.

So, the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices of rank $1$ is a submanifold of $M_2(\mathbb R) \setminus \{0\}$.

Is this also a submanifold of the whole space $M_2(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Are you asking whether the zero-matrix is a singular point of the total locus of det?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because $M_2(\Bbb R)\setminus\{0\}$ is an open subset of $M_2(\Bbb R)$, and thus an embedded submanifold. Embedded submanifold of an embedded submanifold is an embedded submanifold.